# Subsetting variables with missing values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 50 variables (columns) and 30 of them have missing values more than half its own observations.

I want to subset a dataset where those 30 variables with too many missing values are gone. I think I can do it one by one, but I was just wondering if there could be a way to do it more quickly in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic : First iterate through each column using `sapply` and check which all columns have less than half missing values. The output from first line is a logical vector which is used to subset the data.

```
ind <- sapply( colnames(df), function(x) sum(is.na(df[[x]])) < nrow(df)/2)
df <- df[colnames(df)[ind]]
```

Comment: I had a similar problem (extract subset that has only the variables with NAs). I created a working example and Joel's solution in case others want to use it          set.seed(999)
dt0 <- tibble(x1 = letters[1:10],
x2 = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
x3 = rnorm(10, 10, 2),
x4 = rnorm(10, 10, 3),
x5 = rnorm(10, 10, 4)) %>%
mutate(x3=ifelse(x3<9,NA,x3),
x5=ifelse(x5<7,NA,x5))
dt0
dt0 %>% is.na() %>% colSums()

dtNAs <- dt0[colnames(dt0)[
  sapply(colnames(dt0), 
         function(x) 
           sum(is.na(dt0[[x]])) > 0)]]
dtNAs
ncol(dtNAs)
dtNAs %>% variable.names()
dt0 %>% is.na() %>% sum()